# [javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element

Tags: jaxb, cxf, mule

When invkoing a webservice, I get the following exception:

[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"urn:partner.soap.sforce.com", local:"metadataServerUrl"). Expected elements are <{}sessionId>,<{}sandbox>,<{}userId>,<{}passwordExpired>,<{}metadataServerUrl>,<{}userInfo>,<{}serverUrl>]

The response expected is actually an object called LoginResult. But however I see the element names in the exception strace.

The loginResult class is the expected output object from the webservice call. Please suggest how to fix this.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

@XmlRootElement(name = "result")
```

public class LoginResult {

```
@XmlElement(name = "metadataServerUrl")
protected String metadataServerUrl;
@XmlElement(name = "passwordExpired")
protected boolean passwordExpired;
@XmlElement(name = "sandbox")
protected boolean sandbox;
@XmlElement(name = "serverUrl")
protected String serverUrl;
@XmlElement(name = "sessionId")
protected String sessionId;`
@XmlElement(name = "userId")
protected String userId;
@XmlElement(name = "userInfo")
protected GetUserInfoResult userInfo;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to leverage the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation (on a specical class called `package-info` to specify the namespace qualification.  If you already have a package-info.java file make sure it is being compiled.

**package-info.java**

Below is the complete contents of the `package-info.java` file.  You will need to change the package from `example` to the package that contains your domain model to which you want the namespace qualification applied.

```java
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "urn:partner.soap.sforce.com",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**For More Information**

You can find out more information about JAXB and namespace qualification on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: I checked that already. It is exactly as you menioned and being compiled.Still I continue to get this error. Any ideas, what else could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

As @Blaise Doughan mentioned already, you need to make sure you've `package-info` file  and that too in correct `package`.

Did you make sure that line `package com.company.project` in `package-info.java` matches with the package structure of your `LoginResult` class?

Also, print the `XML` response of web-service before unmarshalling it and make sure the element has actually the **namespace** associated.

Comment: Are you sure its `jdk1.0` on server... Who uses jdk1

Answer (score 0):

in my case issue was due to parallel processes using marshaller and unmrashaller which are set and get by JAXBUtil which is single ton. when I made marshaller and unmarshaller synchronized this inconsistent issue is resolved